# Can I create many Job at the same time in kubernetes by client api?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I want to create hundreds of Jobs in kubernetes by its api. Is there any way to do this? I have to create them one by one now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean you have to make 1 API call per object you want to create, but you can certainly write a script for that. Kubernetes does not offer a "bulk create" API endpoint if that's what you are asking, or really much of anything for bulk operations. It's a boring old REST API :)